# Can I use same Class Format list in a Custom Class List?

Tags: c#, datagridview, undo

I'm trying to add an undo function in DataGridView

I implemented the function to process cells one by one but haven't implemented the ability to undo large cells.

```
public class UndoBuffer
{
    public string undoCell { get; set; }
    public int rowIndex { get; set; }
    public int colIndex { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code in question.

When first executed, the list of the class type is declared, and the previous value, row, and column are sequentially saved when cell editing starts and ends.

However, the code does not work properly after performing operations such as delete, paste, or replace.

So I tried to add a list into the class to use when processing with large cells.

Like this

```
 public class UndoBuffer
{
    public string undoCell { get; set; }
    public int rowIndex { get; set; }
    public int colIndex { get; set; }

    public List<UndoBuffer> bufferArray = new List<UndoBuffer>();  //Added Code
}
```

There was no problem with declaring it, but when I tried to use it, I got a grammatical error.

I wrote this code When allocating one by one to the buffer stack

```
 private List<UndoBuffer> undoBuffers = new List<UndoBuffer>(); //Declare CustomList
 ...
 ...
 undoBuffers.Add(new UndoBuffer() { undoCell = beginEditCell, rowIndex = e.RowIndex, colIndex = e.ColumnIndex });
```

And this code was used to allocate a large number of cells on the buffer stack.

```
List<UndoBuffer> undobuffer = new List<UndoBuffer>();

List<UndoBuffer> array = new List<UndoBuffer>();
array.Add(new UndoBuffer()
{
     undoCell = "BeginCell",
     rowIndex = 33,
     colIndex = 2
});
array.Add(new UndoBuffer()
{
     undoCell = "BeginCell",
     rowIndex = 34,
     colIndex = 3
});

**undobuffer.Add(new UndoBuffer() {bufferArray.AddRange(array) });** // Grammar error code
```

Am I coding in the wrong direction, not just a grammatical error?

Please, Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank u

Comment: `new UndoBuffer() {bufferArray = array }`?

Comment: Thank you, 
After fixing the class code ( public List<UndoBuffer> bufferArray = { get; set;} ),  I execute the code and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't have instructions to be executed as a full statement while initializing members when creating a new instance of an object of a type. We can only do assignments, even using a call to method or lambda, so a *function* having a return result. Here it is just procedure call, so that returns nothing.

Therefore, to not replace the whole list, and to be able to add range, we need to decouple the things and write:

```
var buffer = new UndoBuffer();
buffer.bufferArray.AddRange(array);
undobuffer.Add(buffer);
```

Also, `bufferArray` seems to be a [composite](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Association-Composition-and-Aggregation-in-Chash), thus it should be a *get only property* if public, or a *readonly private or protected* field, initialized at declaration time, or in the constructor:

```
public List<UndoBuffer> bufferArray { get; } = new List<UndoBuffer>();
```

I recommend that you improve namings to make them more standard, relevant and clean, such as:

```
public class UndoBuffer
{
    public string UndoCellText { get; set; }
    public int RowIndex { get; set; }
    public int ColIndex { get; set; }

    public List<UndoBuffer> Buffers { get; } = new List<UndoBuffer>();
}
```

[C# Coding Conventions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions)

[C# Naming Conventions](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/C-Sharp-coding-standards-and-naming-conventions/)

[C# Coding Standards and Naming Conventions](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md)

Comment: It was very helpful.. Thank you!!